# Why is my app crashing when trying to connect to firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, the QR code scanner scans a QR code and get the text value in it.
Then this code is run. 
But the app keeps crashing.

I have commented out some parts of the code and found out that when the DatabaseReference part is added, the app crashes

```
    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {

        final String scanResult = result.getText();


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImageView);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_character_name);

        DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("stories").child(scanResult);
        dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String characterName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String downloadURL = dataSnapshot.child("DownloadURL").getValue().toString();
                textView.setText(characterName);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Add the stack trace

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: App crashes when it's running on the phone. Not in the build. The app builds and installs in the phone perfectly. It's when the app is turned on the phone and a QR code is scanned that it starts crashing.

Answer (score -1):

Without the stack trace, it is not possible to find a reason.

However, a possible reason can be if scanResult is null.

Comment: App crashes when it's running on the phone. Not in the build. The app builds and installs in the phone perfectly. It's when the app is turned on the phone and a QR code is scanned that it starts crashing.Is it possible to obtain a stack trace of that?